# @angular/cli: ng new angular, error angular cli unknown option --silent

Tags: angular, npm

I am trying to create a new angular cli project but it shows me error when I am creating one with `ng new project`

```
  $ng new project
  create project/README.md (1023 bytes)
  create project/.angular-cli.json (1242 bytes)
  create project/.editorconfig (245 bytes)
  create project/.gitignore (544 bytes)
  create project/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
  create project/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
  create project/src/environments/environment.ts (387 bytes)
  create project/src/favicon.ico (5430 bytes)
  create project/src/index.html (294 bytes)
  create project/src/main.ts (370 bytes)
  create project/src/polyfills.ts (3114 bytes)
  create project/src/styles.css (80 bytes)
  create project/src/test.ts (642 bytes)
  create project/src/tsconfig.app.json (211 bytes)
  create project/src/tsconfig.spec.json (283 bytes)
  create project/src/typings.d.ts (104 bytes)
  create project/e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts (289 bytes)
  create project/e2e/app.po.ts (208 bytes)
  create project/e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json (235 bytes)
  create project/karma.conf.js (923 bytes)
  create project/package.json (1292 bytes)
  create project/protractor.conf.js (722 bytes)
  create project/tsconfig.json (363 bytes)
  create project/tslint.json (3012 bytes)
  create project/src/app/app.module.ts (316 bytes)
  create project/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
  create project/src/app/app.component.html (1141 bytes)
  create project/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (986 bytes)
  create project/src/app/app.component.ts (207 bytes)

  error: unknown option `--silent'

Error: Package install failed, see above.
Package install failed, see above.
```

On Google there is no information about it and I tried to reinstall @angular/cli and clear cache for npm but it didn't help. Any suggestions?

npm version: 5.6.0

angular cli: 1.7.4

node: 7.2.0 (updated to 9.11.1 but it didn't help(

Comment: hi can you update node and angular/cli version

Comment: hi @Robert, updated.. sorry forgot

Comment: Hi can you update node version let's check it must be working

Comment: I updated node to 9.11.1 but it didn't help

Comment: It could be a permission issue. What's the path that the project is in?

Comment: the angular is here: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/ and the project on Desktop

Answer (score 3):

Try using

```
--skipTests=true
```

Hope this help !

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the npm by running `npm i -g npm` (To 5.8.0).

Comment: Tried but didn't help

Answer (score -2):

Please try

ng config -g cli.packageManager npm

may be packagemanager is set to yarn